# swift firebase query not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make query for firebase realtime database from the swift.

But the following code is not working.

```
var keyvalue = "somevalue"

Database.database().reference().child("users")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "key1").queryEqual(toValue: keyvalue.lowercased())
    .observe(.value, with: {(snapshot)  in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            // do some action  
            // block1
        } else {
           // do some action if not exist 
           // block2
        }
    })
```

I made breakpoint into "block1", "block2".
but code is not reached block1 or block2.
What is wrong in my code?

Firebase database structure is like below.

```
{
  // some nodes..
  "users": {
    "auto_key1": {
      "key1": "key1val",
      "key2": "key2val"
    },
    "auto_key2": {
      "key1": "key1val",
      "key2": "key2val"
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

I think this is enough to explain the structure.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `/users` (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you. I've updated question.

Comment: The values in the JSON and code don't match. But assuming that is a typo (please always create a working [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we don't have to assume), the listener should trigger. Are you sure the user running the query has permission to read the data?

Comment: yes. sometimes that will not in database. my goal is to check whether value is already exists or not.
for example, I'll get the string from textfield, and then I need to check if any sub node of "users" node have that value

Comment: my purpose is to check whether there is "key1" has the value exactly same or not.  To keep unique value like username.

Comment: Your observer should hit, no matter if there are matches or not. The only times it won't hit is if you don't have permission, or don't have a connection to the Firebase database backend.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into an app and it ran fine, and the observe fired correctly. The issue is not the in the posted code. Perhaps your Database was not defined; ensure you have FirebaseApp.configure() in your App delegates *application* function. Oh - and by default you have to be authenticated to read Firebase data so make sure your app authenticares a user before trying to query.

Comment: Hello, in fact, code works fine in xCode emulator.
but this is not working in real device. that's my problem.

Comment: Worked when I ran the app on the device as well.

Comment: yes. I've used many times firebase for app, but this problem was caused first.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to return a child snapshot unless the child's value is equal to "somevalue". Judging by your database, this is impossible because all your "key1" keys have the value of "key1val".

Comment: then how can I check if value exists or not.

Comment: If you are querying by key1 then it has to exist for it to be included in the query. If you instead just want to find out if the key exists, Use the same code. Take out the `queryEqual` and the `queryOrdered` method. and inside the observe part use `if snapshot.hasChild("key1")`

Comment: then I need to check that in the front side?

Comment: Essentially to perform the query, the child *has* to be present to be included and you must include `users: { ".indexOn": ["key1"] }` somewhere in your database rules.

Comment: @ShineHan Hold up. According to your question you want to see if the *value* of the key *key1* exists, right? The above comment about using hasChild is correct if you are looking to see if *any* child nodes contain that key *key1* - that's not what you are looking to do - you are looking for a *value*, not a *key*. Also, the comment about Firebase rules is incorrect as the rules have nothing to do with the query - adding .indexOn increases performance and will not prevent a query from running. Just wanted to clarify that so you don't spend time going the wrong direction.

Comment: Also, this answer should probably be a comment instead as the OP most likely made a typo - this should be a solution, not an observation.

Comment: @Jay sorry mate, I hadn't "unlocked" global comments yet.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in the my iPhone 7 (iOS 11.3).

But When I test the same code in emulator or other iPhones, all was good.

I also don't know why code didn't reach to callback in specific phone but that is not the problem of your code.